# Where can I see a timeline of updates made to the site?

Tags: discussion

Is there a place where I can see updates made to the site with a timestamp, such as feature additions, bug removals, design changes, etc.?

Comment: The technical term would be: changelog.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the changes specific to this site can be found under [status-completed tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed?sort=active&pageSize=50). There aren't many of those.

The majority of feature changes and bug fixes are network-wide, and so they are [listed on the network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445). This community-curated list is pretty thorough, with dates and references. Quote:

> #### December 2015
>
> - 2015-12-23: Question timeline (not moderator timeline) got a new design and features, e.g. [showing who voted to close or
>     reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271797/152859), and more.
> - 2015-12-09: Users with 10k reputation can now [use the `deleted:1` advanced search operator to search their own deleted
>     posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562/152859).
>
> #### November 2015
>
> - 2015-11-09: Comments auto-added from review queues now [indicate as such](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309704).
>
> #### October 2015
>
> - 2015-10-23: It is now possible to [filter your flag history by type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268369/168244).